# "expected constant expression" Error

Tags: visual-c++

I have been trying to make a merge sort code but this error message kept showing up.It says "expected constant expression" even though size is constant in the main function. I tried to fix it but I couldn't. What shall I do ?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void merge(int data[], int size, int first, int mid, int last);

void mergeSort(int data[], int size, int first /*low*/, int last/*high*/)
{
    if(first<last)
    {
        //sort each half
        int mid = (first + last)/2;
        //index of midpoint 
        //sort left half the array [first .... mid]
        mergeSort(data, size, first, mid);
        //sort right half of the array [mid+1 ..... last]
        mergeSort(data, size, mid+1, last);
        //merge the two halves 
        merge(data, size, first, mid, last);
    }
}

void merge(int data[], int size, int first, int mid, int last)
{

    int tempArr[size];
    int i=first;
    int j=mid+1;
    int k=first;

    while (i<=mid && j<=last)
    {
        if (tempArr[i] <= tempArr[j])
        {
            data[k]=tempArr[i];
        }
        else
        {
            data[k] = tempArr[j];
            ++j;
        }
        ++k;
    }

    while (i <= mid)
    {
        data[k] = tempArr[i];
        ++k;
        ++i;
    }
    }

int main()
{
    const int size = 10;
    int arr[size] = {1, 0, 6, 15, 30, 56, 23, 3, 7, 10};
    mergeSort(arr, size, 0, size);
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cout<< arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You declared `int tempArr[size];` but did initialize it before you called its elements.

Comment: But I did in the main function. I even tried to put it under using namespace std; so it will be global still the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several mistakes in your code. I rewrote the code for you :) so you can study it more and see where your mistakes were. There are still many rooms for improvements, though! You may run the code [here](http://ideone.com/sHYTPz).

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void merge(int data[], int size, int first, int mid, int last);

void mergeSort(int data[], int size, int first /*low*/, int last/*high*/)
{
    if(first<last-1) // do it if there are more than one lement
    {
        //sort each half
        int mid = (first + last)/2;
        //index of midpoint 
        //sort left half the array [first .... mid-1]
        mergeSort(data, size, first, mid);
        //sort right half of the array [mid ..... last-1]
        mergeSort(data, size, mid, last);
        //merge the two halves 
        merge(data, size, first, mid, last);
    }
}

void merge(int data[], int size, int first, int mid, int last)
{
    int* tempArr = new int[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        tempArr[i] = data[i];

    int i=first;
    int j=mid;
    int k=first;

    while (i<mid && j<last)
    {
        if (tempArr[i] <= tempArr[j])
        {
            data[k]=tempArr[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            data[k] = tempArr[j];
            ++j;
        }
        ++k;
    }

    while (i < mid)
    {
        data[k] = tempArr[i];
        ++k;
        ++i;
    }
    while (j < last)
    {
        data[k] = tempArr[j];
        ++k;
        ++j;
    }
    delete[] tempArr;
}

int main()
{
    const int size = 10;
    int arr[size] = {1, 0, 6, 15, 30, 56, 23, 3, 7, 10};
    mergeSort(arr, size, 0, size);
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cout<< arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am going to have a look at it, and I am pretty sure I am going to learn more because of your help.

Comment: After having a look at it  and trying to run it, it still give me the same error. The error underlines size in   int tempArr[size]; and says "expected a constant value"

Comment: I included a link to the code where you can run it. It works fine there. What compiler do you use?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Check my updated answer. You can allocate memory dynamically for `tempArr`. This fixes the issue in VS.